# How to redirect programmatically inside a module to an external url?

Tags: 8, routes

I am trying to redirect to a page after I unset a session.
I read [this article](https://x-team.com/blog/drupal-goto/) but I am pretty new to Drupal module building.

Here this amazing guy says to do the comming thing:

> If you know that the destination is an external URL then you are
>   encouraged to use TrustedRedirectResponse instead:
>
> ```
> return new RedirectResponse(\Drupal::url('<front>', [], ['absolute' => TRUE]));
>   return new TrustedRedirectResponse('http://www.bbc.com/');
> ```

I don't understand how I should use this code and where to put it...

Any help would be great 
This is my controller file content.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\achva_sso\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;


class SsoController extends ControllerBase{
    public function ssoLogout(){
        unset($_SESSION['name']);

        if(isset($_SESSION['name'])){
            $status = $_SESSION['name'] .' is logged in';
        }else{
            $status = 'is logged out';
        }
        return[
            '#type' => 'markup',
            '#markup' => '<p>' . $status . '</p>' ,
        ];


    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if you want to redirect to an external page this can be your code:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\achva_sso\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\TrustedRedirectResponse;

class SsoController extends ControllerBase{
    public function ssoLogout(){
        unset($_SESSION['name']);

        // Redirect.
        return new TrustedRedirectResponse('http://www.bbc.com/');

    }
}
```

In this case, the redirection will happen when your ssoLogout() method will be called.

Comment: Thank you! but actoually I want to redirect to an external url...Is it possible to replace the `<front>` with the wanted url?

Comment: As the documentation states, you need to use TrustedRedirectResponse instead to redirect to external URLs.

Comment: But don't send, return the response as stated in the documentation.

Comment: @DavSev I come from update and test the answer and it works

Comment: Thanks @Kevin I thought it was to an internal URL.

Comment: @4k4 can you share the doc link? I used before the send and it works fine, jut to be updated I want to read more about this, thanks.

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer, I was referring to the link in the question, which returns the response. Why you shouldn't send the response is because of the http kernel interface used by Drupal (REQ->DrupalKernel->REP), see https://stackphp.com/